# Replace inflate with lzma when boot start in Vxworks

Tags: bootstrapping, vxworks, inflate

Due to ROM size I have to compress the bootstrap with LZMA instead of deflate,
When the bootstrap is loaded, it is uncompressed by inflate by default from ROM to RAM.
Since the bootstrap is compressed by LZMA, it must be uncompressed by LZMA instead of inflate.

So how can I replace inflate with LZMA?

Answer (score 0):

Problem soloved,
1. modify the ..\target\h\make\rules.vxWorks,  use "programStore -f tmp.bin -c 4 -o tmp.Z" instead of $(COMPRESS) < tmp.bin > tmp.Z, you may want to add a new rule for your project

2. modify romStart.c, use decompress_lzma_7z for decompressing instead of UNCMP_RTN in romStart()